# AjaxControlToolkit Does not work with no error seen

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AJAXControlToolkit in an Asp.net app (C#), on VS2013.

The toolkit was installed using NUGET, and in my bin I do see the dll of ajaxcontroltoolit, also in my project refrences.

I have added all the controls from the dll to my ToolBox, And I do add the scriptManager that is needed (I tried to remove this to make sure I get an error when I load my page, and I do. When I add the scriptmanger the error is gone).

Now that my project does recognise the tag perfix as I added one, and I have the scriptManager, I add several extenders to my page.
for example:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
  <asp:TextBox ID="bday" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender"  TargetControlID="bday" runat="server" />
```

But on runtime, nothing happens. none of the extenders that I use works. The textbox above for example, is just a plain textbox, Nothing happens with it or with any other extender I use.

I get no errors at all.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender" PopupButtonID="bday" TargetControlID="bday" runat="server" />
```

you have't  used PopupButtonID in your code try using that

Add this to your **web.config** file

```
    <pages>
      <controls>

 <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" 
assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.10920.16768, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
        <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
            tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
```

**Tutorial :** [**How to use ASP.NET AJAX Calender Extender**](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/407460/How-to-use-ASP-NET-AJAX-Calender-Extender)

[**How to Register Ajax toolkit in web config**](https://sites.google.com/site/benchia1979/programming/csharp/howtoregisterajaxtoolkitinwebconfig)

Comment: I now get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'UI' of undefined" and in the HTML the line with the error is $create(Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior, {"firstDayOfWeek":0,"format":"dd/MM/yyyy","id":"MainContent_CalendarExtender"}, null, null, $get("MainContent_bday"));

Comment: i now get Uncaught Error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll. NOTICE I DO USE TOOLKITSCRIPTMANAGER NOW

Comment: in the ajax toolkit tool you will be having toolkit script manager remove script manager and use toolkitscriptmanagere

Comment: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2013/09/30/ajax-control-toolkit-now-supports-jquery

Comment: Again,  NOTICE I DO USE TOOLKITSCRIPTMANAGER NOW . i do not use the script manager

Comment: wat version of ajax you are using

Comment: check the link for registering web.config file hope that helps, let me know

Comment: The error is nothing with the web.config. it says "AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43699/discussion-between-amarnath-and-programer)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

    <asp:TextBox ID="bday" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender"  TargetControlID="bday" runat="server PopupButtonID="bday" />
```